# How to get index by using XmlDocument functions? C#

Tags: c#, xml, webforms

I created a C# Web Form Application, and I want to get index from specific object. This is what I have for now. In this exercise, I want to input login name and password in order to get info from that specific person. Duplicated name/password is allowed. What I can think of is get index from nodes, and then use `XmlNodeList info = reader.GetElementsByTagName("Info");` and `textBox1.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Info")[index].InnerText;` I need to find that specific index, but I feel a little bit confuse about that. Hope someone can give me any suggestions, and new idea on how to do it, thank you!

```
private int GetIndex(string loginname, string password)
{
    reader = new XmlDocument();
    reader.Load(@filepath);
    XmlNodeList loginN = reader.GetElementsByTagName("Loginname");
    XmlNodeList Pass = reader.GetElementsByTagName("Password");
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Authentication>
  <User xmlns="">
    <Loginname>Admin</Loginname>
    <Password>232</Password>
    <Info>Hello, I'm first person</Info>
  </User>
  <User xmlns="">
    <Loginname>Admin</Loginname>
    <Password>4445</Password>
    <Info>Hello, I'm second person</Info>
  </User>
</Authentication>
```

Comment: Using .SelectNodes() you could find the nodes quickly with a XPath query string. I do not know of a method to get a nodes index. If you get the XmlNodes using SelectNodes then loop through all children of Authenticaton with a for loop and find the XmlNodes that matches those you found. Then you would have your indexes.

Comment: @Wolf5 May you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get `Info` by given `Loginname` and `Password` then you can use XPath.

```
string username = "Admin";
string password = "232";
string xPathQuery = 
    String.Format("Authentication/User[Loginname='{0}' and Password='{1}']",
    username, password);

XmlNode node = reader.SelectSingleNode(xPathQuery);    

if (node == null)
{
    // Incorrect username \ password
} else {
    string info = node.SelectSingleNode("User/Info").InnerText;
    textBox1.Text = info;
}
```

Note that if there are several `Users` with the same username and the same password - `SelectSingleNode` will pick the **first** one.

Comment: I have tired your format, but `XmlNode node = reader.SelectSingleNode(xPathQuery);` gave me null. However, I input correct username and password.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev @har07 I found out one error that `String.Format("Authentication/User[Loginname='{0}' and Password='{1}']", username, password);` need to replace as `String.Format("//User[Loginname='{0}' and Password='{1}']", username, password);`. Not sure why but it works! Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("XmlFile1.xml");
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("Authentication/User[Loginname='Admin' and Password='4445']");

var childnodes = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
for (int i = 0; i < childnodes.Count; i++)
{
    if (node == childnodes[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INDEX IS: " + i);
    }
}
```